# Concatenating strings to iteration numbers in batch

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I have the following batch script:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "base_name=distribution"
set "dir_net_name=dir_net"


FOR %%? IN (1,1,10) DO (
set "itnum=%%?"
set "name=%dir_net_name%\%base_name%_%itnum%"
echo %name%
)
pause
```

I have the following problems:
(1) The loop iterates over 1, 1, and 10 rather than 1 through 10
(2) I want to concatenate dir_net_name + \ + base_name + _ + itnum, but itnum does not show
(3) name does not show, echo does nothing

I have tried this over and over again, but still not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "base_name=distribution"
set "dir_net_name=dir_net"

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO (
set "name=%dir_net_name%\%base_name%_%%i"
echo !name!
)

pause
```

- ad 1) see `help for` for details on `/L` switch.
- ad 2) `%itnum%` is redundant here. If you still need it use it as `!itnum!`.
- ad 3) `%name%` is evaluated before `FOR` loop starts, use `!name!` instead.

Comment: eliminate the `name` intermediate variable, and then delayed expansion is not needed: `echo %dir_net_name%\%base_name%_%%i`

Comment: @dbenham: +1, but I'll leave it there as it answers third subquestion.